# MS Outlook 2010: Filter messages except where I'm the only To: recipient

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010

I'm trying to filter certain messages *except* if they are sent only to me, in the sense that I'm the only recipient on the `To:` line (the only recipient expected to take action). There are other recipients, but they are all `Cc:` recipients (parties in the loop, not expected to take action).

I tried the *"except if sent only to me"* exception, but it is not matching messages which are only `To:` me and `Cc:` to others. Such messages still get processed by the filter.

I also tried looking at this from the angle of creating a positive filter for these exceptions and inserting it ahead of the main filter, but couldn't find any way of matching messages where my name is the only entry in the To: header, regardless of how many recipients there are.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to create two rules:

1. "run a script" that checks the required condition and sets some x-header as a flag for the next rule using VBA.

Simething like this:

```
Sub ImTheOnlyTo(Item As MailItem)
    ...
    Set objProp = Item.UserProperties.Add("x-imtheonlyto", 1)
    objProp.Value = "yes"        
End Sub
```

2. "with specific words in the message header" that checks the presence of the previously set x-header (like x-imtheonlyto).

Comment: Do script rules execute on the server, or are these client-only rules? I should clarify that I'm not interested in filtering on the e-mail-client side.

Comment: Unfortunately, "run a script" rules are client-only.